# Why can't I see any string fields in graduated renderer?

Tags: qgis, style

After the join I can see all my data in the attributes of the layer but when I want to select statistics in the graduated style to categorize, I don't see them. I see that the real type variables and not those of type string. Are there any parameters to be changed?

---

original:

après avoir fait la jointure je vois bien l'ensemble de mes données dans les attributs de la carte mais quand je veux sélectionner les statistiques dans l'onglet style pour catégoriser, je ne les vois pas. Je ne vois que les variables de type real et pas celles de type string. Y a t-il un paramètre à modifier?

Answer (score 3):

Graduated renderer is only available for numeric fields. I does not support text values. That's why you cannot even chose them in the drop-down list.